# Vue.js, GitHub, Heroku - How to dynamically, securely set environment vars?

Tags: vue.js, github, heroku, environment-variables

I have an application written in Vue.js, and the source code is stored in GitHub. I also have that source code connected to pipelines in Heroku. I am trying to figure out how to best manage environment variables securely with this setup.

Currently, I am using `.env.local`, `.env.dev`, and `.env.prod` files in my Vue app to manage environment variables. However, I need to be able to manage some of these settings elsewhere, like keys that I don't want to be visible/accessible client-side. I have tried using Heroku's environment variable settings, but those don't seem to be accessible to or acknowledged by my Vue app, which I suppose makes sense. I'm just not sure where to go from here. This seems like a pretty basic problem that *someone* must have solved before.

EDIT: I am prfixing my variables with `VUE_APP_`, such as `VUE_APP_API`. Then I am access that value n the app via this syntax: `process.env.VUE_APP_API`.

Comment: When you try to use Heroku's environment variables are you making sure to prepend them with `VUE_APP` and accessing them client side with `process.env.VUE_APP_SOME_CONFIG_VAR`

Comment: Yeah, I am. The environment variables are just being ignored though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to load your enviornment variables from a single `.env` file.

You can define your enviornemnt vars in a file named `.env`

```
VUE_APP_SOME_VAR=someVARvalue
VUE_APP_SOME_OTHER_VAR=someOTHERVARValue
```

Then you can load these vars from `.env` in any file like this

```js
require('dotenv').config()

//...
//...

process.env.VUE_APP_SOME_VAR

//...
//...
```

You can learn more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Additionally, you should not commit your `.env` file to your version control software as it might contain sensitive authentication keys. You can configure Heroku to use the same enviornment variables by setting Configuration Variables in the apps settings page.